# Fire event once on DOM change

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I'm using the following jQuery:

```
$('table').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
   myfunction();
});
```

The contents of the table are modified by another function. However, this triggers the above for every element in the table that is changed.

Is there a way to fire only once after all table-changes have been made?

Comment: Don't use DOM mutation events at all, they're deprecated and actively being removed from browsers. Use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and watch the `table` for subtree modifications.

Comment: Give the function that is doing the modifications the "myfunction" function as a callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to register once for an event. In this Snippet click the button to add a `<td>` to table, thereby triggering the DOMSubtreeModified event only once. Note any further modifications to table do not trigger anything.

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('table tr').append('<td>TEST</td>');
});


$('table').one("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  alert('MODIFIED');
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>addTD</button>
```